# How to limit the number of terms (terms acts like categories)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

Hello i have created taxonomy in custom post type that act like category.

then i have created terms that acts like categories.

i have create widget that show all terms from taxonomy. all works great.

but i can"t understand how to limit the number of terms to show.

i have created input in my widget. so if i put some number i want the widget will limit to show only this number of terms.

thanks for help!

the code to show all terms is:

```
$terms = get_terms('new_category');
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'new_category' );
    echo '<li><a href="' . $term_link . '"><div>' . $term->name . '</div></a></li>';

}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)?

Answer (score 7):

```
number 
    (integer) The maximum number of terms to return. Default is to return them all. 

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms
```

So...

```
$terms = get_terms('new_category',array('number' => 5));
```

But there is a good chance that some of your terms will never show up. You will get the first five or the last five (in the example) depending on the sort order. You may want something like this instead:

```
$terms = get_terms('category');
if (!is_wp_error($terms)) {
  $pick = ($pick <= count($terms)) ?: count($terms);
  $rand_terms = array_rand($terms, $pick);
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach ($rand_terms as $key => $term) {
    $term =  $terms[$term];
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
    var_dump($term_link);
    if (!is_wp_error($term_link)) {
      echo '<li><a href="' . $term_link . '"><div>' . $term->name . '</div></a></li>';
    }
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$terms = get_terms('new_category', array('number' => 4));
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'new_category' );
    echo '<li><a href="' . $term_link . '"><div>' . $term->name . '</div></a></li>';

}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

change number value as required

```
$terms = get_terms('new_category', 'number=10');
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'new_category' );
    echo '<li><a href="' . $term_link . '"><div>' . $term->name . '</div></a></li>';

}
echo '</ul>';
```